# Validate filename in c# through regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a filename with this format : LetterNumber_Enrollment_YYYYMMDD_HHMM.xml

```
string filename = "Try123_Enrollment_20130102_1200.xml";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[a-zA-z]_Enrollment_[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{4}\\.xml");
if (pattern.IsMatch(filename))
{
return isValid = true;
}
```

However, I can't make it to work.

Any thing that i missed here?

Comment: In what way can you not make it work?

Comment: try one "\" instead of 2

Comment: It must pass the if condition.

Comment: [a-zA-Z] will not pick up any numbers in the first section (so it will not match "Try123", and it will only pick up a single letter at that.  Your date Regex is also wrong - it should be [0-9]{8}, not {6}.

Comment: I tried remove one "\" but still not working.

Comment: You missed some serious quantifiers `[a-zA-z]+[0-9]+_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml`

Comment: @Hamza - You should post that as an answer with an explanation of the quantifiers :)

Comment: @Tim I posted that as a comment since I was on a hurry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not matching digits at the beginning. Your pattern should be: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml$` to match given string.

Changes:

1. Your string starts with alphanumeric string before first `_` symbol so you need to check both (letters and digits).
2. After `Environment_` part you have digits with the length of 8 not 6.
3. No need of double `\`. You need to escape just dot (i.e. `\.`).

[Demo app:](http://ideone.com/H9uoHi)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test {
    static void Main() {
        string filename = "Try123_Enrollment_20130102_1200.xml";
        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml$");
        if (pattern.IsMatch(filename))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Matched");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i do that like this: new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml$"); ?

Comment: @Gerald Updated with demo.

Comment: It shows me an error on the "@" saying that "Keyword, identifier, or string expected".

Comment: @Gerald Are you using this in `razor`? Oh, glad that I helped you. ;)

Comment: My mistake is this: @^" instead of @"^. No, i am using it on class.

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is nowhere near your actual string:

- you only match a single letter at the start (and no digits) so `Try123` doesn't match
- you match 6 digits instead of 8 at the date part so `20130102` doesn't match
- you have escaped your backslash near the end (`\\.xml`) but you've also used `@` on your string: with `@` you don't need to escape.

Try this instead:

```
@"[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml"
```

I've assumed you want only three letters and three numbers at the start; in fact you may want this:

```
@"[\w]*_Enrollment_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}\.xml"
```

Comment: \w will match the underscore, as well as letters and digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it matches letters and digits at the beginning and also ensures that the date is valid.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+_Enrollment_(19|20)\d\d(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_[0-9]{4}\.xml
```

As an aside, to test your regular expressions try the free regular expression designer from Rad Software, I find that it helps me work out complex expressions beforehand.

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It will help me a lot.